# HTML/Javascript printing a form on click event

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script on my HTML file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function addTeacher() {
        $("#addTeacher").click(function addTeacher() {
            $('#conteudo').html("FORM CODE HERE");
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

---

The form i want printed on the div #addTeacher:

```
<form  method="post" action="auth.php" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success" />

</form>
```

I paste the form code between the quotation marks but when i click the button, nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

The div code:

```
<div class="container" id="conteudo">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

The button:

```
 <button type="button" id="addTeachers" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar Professor</button>
```

Comment: Either of the elements referred in the script can't be found from your HTML.

Comment: Where is "conteudo" defined ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i forget to add the div code

    <div class="container" id="conteudo">
      <div class="row">
      </div>
    </div>

Comment: The button is still missing, basicly, [your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/FrPfQ/).

Comment: I want the form appearing only i click the button with the id #addTeacher.

Comment: There's not `button #addTeacher` in your code... Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @PatrickMaia Please edit your question to provide the additional HTML that is missing from it. Don't paste it in the comments.

Comment: Curious, is this syntax correct `$("#addTeacher").click(function addTeacher() {`? What is `addTeacher()` doing in there?

Comment: @asprin [function operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), though names are useless in OP's code.

Comment: why do you have two function with the name of `addTeacher`?

Comment: try to do this with javascript it would be easier to you and also to understand it !

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're referencing the right ID for your button. `addTeachers` is not the same as `addTeacher`.

Second, make sure you get your quote marks right and escape your line breaks. Getting either wrong will cause a syntax error.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2AMg4/1/

Answer (score 0):

here you can also do this with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var add = function(){

        var parent = document.getElementById("row");

    var form1 = document.createElement("form");
        form1.setAttribute("method","post");
        form1.setAttribute("action","auth.php");
        form1.setAttribute("role","form");

    var form_groupe = document.createElement("div");
        form_groupe.setAttribute("class","form-groupe");

    var form_groupe2 = document.createElement("div");
        form_groupe.setAttribute("class","form-groupe");



    var login = document.createElement("input");
        login.setAttribute("type","text");
        login.setAttribute("name","login");
        login.setAttribute("id","login");
        login.setAttribute("class","form-controll");
        login.setAttribute("placeholder","login");

    var pass = document.createElement("input");
        pass.setAttribute("type","password");
        pass.setAttribute("name","senha");
        pass.setAttribute("id","senha");
        pass.setAttribute("class","form-controll");
        pass.setAttribute("placeholder","Senha");   

    var submit = document.createElement("input");   
        submit.setAttribute("type","submit");
        submit.setAttribute("name","login");
        submit.setAttribute("class","btn btn-success");

    form_groupe.appendChild(login);
    form_groupe2.appendChild(pass); 
    form1.appendChild(form_groupe);
    form1.appendChild(form_groupe2);    
    form1.appendChild(submit);  
    parent.appendChild(form1);  
};
</script> 

<div class="container" id="conteudo">
  <div class="row" id="row">
  </div>
</div>
 <button type="button" id="addTeachers" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add();">Adicionar Professor</button>
```

here is the [`working code`](http://jsfiddle.net/zL9p7/)